# Search An Array Consisting of Sub-Arrays For the Largest Number and Return in a New Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I am working on a coding challenge to take a given array which consists of sub-arrays, search for the largest number in each sub-array, and finally return a new array consisting only of the largest numbers. My thought process was to create variables out of each subarray, write a for-loop comparing each value within the array, then push the largest value to a new array. After writing my first for-loop I tested my code and see that I am getting an unexpected result of the entire first subarray being pushed into my new array. I am looking for the mistake before I write the next three loops. Thank you. Edit: This is for beginner JavaScript coders and the suggestion indicates to use comparison operators in your solution.

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
      var one = arr[0];
      var two = arr[1];
      var three = arr[2];
      var four = arr[3];
      var newArr = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < one.length; i++){
        var oneLrg = 0;
        if (one[i] > oneLrg){
          oneLrg = one[i];
          }
        newArr.push(oneLrg);
      }  

  return arr;
}

console.log(largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]])); //This test case returns [4,5,1,3] instead of just [5]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using [`>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Greater_than_operator_%28%3E%29):

```js
var newArr = [];
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; ++i) {           // Iterate array
  var maximum = -Infinity;                  // Initial maximum
  for(var j=0; j<arr[i].length; ++j)        // Iterate subarrays
    if(arr[i][j] > maximum)                 // Compare
      maximum = arr[i][j];                  // Update maximum
  newArr.push(maximum);                     // Store the real maximum
}
```

Using [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max):

```js
var newArr = [];
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; ++i) {           // Iterate array
  var maximum = -Infinity;                  // Initial maximum
  for(var j=0; j<arr[i].length; ++j)        // Iterate subarrays
    maximum = Math.max(maximum, arr[i][j]); // Update maximum
  newArr.push(maximum);                     // Store the real maximum
}
```

Adding [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```js
var newArr = [];
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; ++i)     // Iterate array
  newArr.push(                      // Store ...
    Math.max.apply(Math, arr[i])    // ... the maximum of the subarray
  );
```

Adding ECMAScript 5 [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map),

```js
var newArr = arr.map(function(subarray) {
  return Math.max.apply(Math, subarray);
});
```

Adding ECMAScript 5 [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind),

```js
var newArr = arr.map(Function.apply.bind(Math.max, Math));
```

Or adding ECMAScript 6 [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator),

```js
var newArr = arr.map(subarray => Math.max(...subarray));
```

Comment: This challenge is designed for beginning coders and has the recommendation to use comparison operators. Could you picture a solution with this in mind? Or could you provide some explanation because I don't understand the code I am looking at. Thank you @oriol

Comment: Thanks so much for the very detailed answer here. Awesome. I have a couple questions, if that is ok. 1) Why is the initial maximum set to "-Infinity"? Would setting to "0" also work? 2) In the second for-loop is "arr[i][j]" the syntax for locating a specific value in a subarray? I didn't know if there was a syntax for that but it would obviously be very useful.

Comment: @AustinHansen You can set the initial maximum to 0 if you know the numbers won't be negative. And yes, `arr[i][j]` first accesses the `i`-th subarray, and then returns its `j`-th number. That means you don't have to store each subarray in a variable.

Comment: Great explanation! "-Infinity" is a superior choice as it could also complete the task with negative numbers included. Thank you so much for a seriously detailed answer and explanation. It is so much better to learn than to just have the answer. Awesome! @oriol

Comment: @AustinHansen Not at all :) Also note that choosing 0 or -Infinity will matter if some subarray is empty. So if you know the numbers will be positive, 0 might make sense.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're overwriting `oneLrg` at each loop iteration, and pushing it inside the same loop, so you're comparing each value to 0 and then, as `one[i]` is bigger, saving it.

Try this:

```
var oneLrg = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < one.length; i++){
    if (one[i] > oneLrg){
        oneLrg = one[i];
    }
}
newArr.push(oneLrg);
```

Comment: very good point. however when i make this change i still get the unexpected result of [4, 5, 5, 5]. any ideas?

Comment: @Austin Hansen Only the fact that you're returning `arr`when you want to get `newArr`, but this result doesn't has any sense either

Comment: Yes that typo is not present in the code that I ran. I was returning newArr. Sorry. Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1):

No doubt that @Austin Hansen and I are leveraging the same learning environment for this challenge: Free Code Camp.

Having just worked through this challenge myself (FCC calls them "Bonfires"), I figured I'd provide solution that heavily dovetails from @Oriol 's excellent ">" solution.

I've included a specific note about the code blocks because to us newbies (at FCC or elsewhere), the absence of such can give us fits for hours : )

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
 var finalArray = [];     
 for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { // iterates through each array
   var max = -Infinity;
   for(j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) { // iterates through each sub-array 
      if(arr[i][j] > max) { // comparing each successive element within the sub-array to what is currently stored as max
        max = arr[i][j]; //if the ">" comparison is true then max gets updated
      }  
    }
    finalArray.push(max); // ensure this is OUTside of the j for loop. putting it INside the j for loop returns a very long (and wrong) array. try it. 
  }
  console.log(finalArray);
  return finalArray;
}

largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]], "");
```

https://jsbin.com/puweci/edit?js,console

FCC recognizes the follow solution which doesn't NOT leverage Array.push().

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  var results = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     var max = -Infinity;
     for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
        if (arr[i][j] > max) {
        max = arr[i][j];
        }
     }

    results[i] = max;
  }

  return results;
}

largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]], "");
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will take two numbers and return their maximum:

```
var greatest = function(a,b){ return Math.max(a,b); };
```

This function will take an array of numbers and apply the `greatest` function to each number in turn (using the [`.reduce( callbackFunction, initialValue )`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method of arrays) to get the maximum value in the array:

```
var findMaximum = function( arr ){ return arr.reduce( greatest, Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY ); };
```

The `findMaximum` function can be simplified by just calling `Math.max()` with all the array values (eliminating the need for the `greatest` function); like this:

```
var findMaximum = function( arr ){ return Math.max.apply( Math, arr ); };
```

This function will take an array (of arrays) and call `findMaximum` on each element of it and return a new array containing those maximums (using the [`.map( callbackFunction )`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method on an array):

```
var largestOfFour = function( arr ){ return arr.map( findMaximum ); };
```

Answer (score 0):

This post hasn't had any new updates in about 3 months, but I figured I would post my solution to this problem as it looks a bit different than most of the other solutions posted thus far. Figured someone might find it helpful!

I am using quite a few built in method functions( .forEach, .sort, .push, .shift) a quick google search will explain each of these fairly well if you are unsure of how they work. https://developer.mozilla.org is a great resource for these.

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  var newArr = [];                              //set up new empty array
  arr.forEach(function(subArr){                 //iterate through array with .each function
    subArr.sort(function(a, b){                 //use .sort to place largest number of each subarray into index[0]
      return a < b;     
    });
    newArr.push(subArr.shift());                //use .push method to .shift the index[0] number to newArr
  });
  return newArr;                            
}

largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this:

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  var newArr=[];
  largestnum=0;
  for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
      for(j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
      if(arr[i][j]>largestnum)
        largestnum=arr[i][j];
        }
       newArr.push(largestnum);
      largestnum=0;
    }
return newArr;
}

largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

@orion - Your answer to me was not working. If the push is inside the if statement was pushing numbers that were not suppose to be in the array. As a result the first would push [4,5] and wound't work. So I moved the push out of the for statement and reset the lgstNumber to 0 also after so it wouldn't use it for the next sub-array. This worked for me...

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  // You can do this!
  var newArr = [];
  var lgstNumber = -  Infinity;
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++){
      if(lgstNumber < arr[i][j]){
        lgstNumber = arr[i][j];
      }
    }
    newArr.push(lgstNumber);
    lgstNumber = 0;
  }
  return newArr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
    return arr.map(function(subArray) {
        return subArray.reduce(function(firstArray, secondArray) {
            return firstArray > secondArray ? firstArray : secondArray;
        });
    });
}
largestOfFour([[13, 27, 18, 26],[4, 5, 1, 3],[32, 35, 37, 39],[1000, 1001, 857, 1]
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

its more efficient.

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {


  for(var x=0;x<arr.length;x++)
    {
       for(var y=0;y<arr[x].length;y++)
        {
           arr[x]=arr[x].sort(function(a,b)
                   {
         return b-a;
       });

     }
}
  var array=[];
  for(var a=0;a<arr.length;a++)
{
  for(var b=0;b<arr[a].length;b++)
    {
      if(b==0)
        {
          array[a]=arr[a][b];
        }
    }


}
  return array;

}

largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```