# Using reduce() within map() on array of arrays

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a freecodecamp challenge, and am wondering why my code doesn't work and how to correct it.

The objective is to "Return an array consisting of the largest number from each provided sub-array."

My attempt was to map the input array using reduce as the map function:

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
    arr = arr.map(function(innerArray){
       innerArray = innerArray.reduce(function(previousValue,currentValue){
           return currentValue > previousValue ? currentValue : previousValue;
       });
    });
    return arr;
}

console.log(largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3],[1, 2, 3, 4]]));
```

Currently the output is: `[undefined, undefined]`

How should I fix my code?

Comment: You're assigning to `innerArray`, but not returning anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inside the `map` callback, you should return the result of `reduce`:

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  return arr.map(function(innerArray){
    return innerArray.reduce(function(previousValue,currentValue){
      return currentValue > previousValue ? currentValue : previousValue;
    });
  });
}
```

Note there are [shorter ways of doing that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31094841/1529630).

Comment: Great, thanks! This really clears up how the array functions work.

Comment: Chose this as correct because it answers my specific question even if my original method wasn't the best way.

Answer (score 4):

There's an easier way

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
    return arr.map(function(innerArray) {
      return Math.max.apply(null, innerArray);
    });
}
```

`Math.max` can be called with multiple arguments, as in `Math.max(3,4,5,6)` would return `6`.

using `apply` we can pass an array of arguments to a function, as in `.apply(thisValue, [3,4,5,6])`  and do the same thing.

Since there's an array of arrays, we can map the outer array, and return the result of `Math.max.apply(thisValue, innerArray)`, and since the `thisValue` is unimportant here, just passing `null` is fine.

Comment: Thanks, I was having a hard time using Math.max with map() so I went the reduce() route. This clears it up for the future.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way to solve this

```js
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  return arr.map(function(innerArray) {
    // sort innerArray ascending
    return innerArray.sort(function sort(a, b) {
      return a > b;
    }).pop(); // << get the last element (the max)
  });
}

var result = largestOfFour([
  [4, 5, 1, 3],
  [1, 2, 3, 4]
]);
console.log(result);
document.write(result);
```