# find smallest number in array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

What would be the most efficient way to take n smallest numbers from Array in Javascript

```
[[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]
```

Result is

```
[1,13,32,1]
```

Comment: Do you really mean "most efficient", or do you just mean "some way that works"? Is there something wrong with `array.map(subarray => Math.min(...subarray))`?

Comment: @torazaburo just wondering, wouldn't that already be the most efficient way, at least algorithmically? You must look at all arrays to accumulate the mins array. You also must look at every number in each array to find a min. Thus the best conceivable runtime is `O(#ofArrays * largestArrayLength)`.

Comment: Did you copy your input from [Search An Array Consisting of Sub-Arrays For the Largest Number and Return in a New Array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31094820/1529630)? Just replace `Math.max` with `Math.min`.

Comment: @nem035 Any non-stupid way will be optimal because you need to at least read all the numbers in order to determine the minimum, and reading each number once is enough.

Comment: I'm sorry if my question as others ask, because I'm new here. thanks for help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `Math.min()`. It gets numbers and returns the minimum from them. I used the map() function to iterate over each nested array, then have used `Math.min()` with the ..., which will destroy the nested array and pass it to the function like `Math.min(4,5,1,3)` for the first nested one

#### ES6

```js
var arr = [[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]];

var minArr = arr.map(item => Math.min(...item));

console.log(minArr);
```

#### ES5

```js
var arr = [[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]];

var minArr = arr.map(function(array){
  return Math.min.apply(null,array)
});

console.log(minArr);
```

Comment: Just for variety, I have added a `ES5` version as well. If it is not required, please revert it

Comment: @Rajesh thank you, but you deleted my description :) I write it again